# Jenkins Pipeline - Switch node version dynamically

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, nvm

Is there a way we can set NodeJS version dynamically in Jenkins Pipeline. I am not able to make available nvm as well inside the pipeline.

```
sh 'export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm'
sh 'source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

script.sh: line 2: nvm: command not found
```

None of this helped. Multiple teams using the pipeline need specific version of nodeJS. Earlier with non-pipeline jobs, this used to work using nvm.

Comment: you can add nodes with a different version of node is one way. Another way can be done with specifying tool.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#tools

Comment: I am trying to give the flexibility to project teams to chose a node version, similar to nvm use <node version>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `choice` [parameter](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters) and use it in [tools](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#tools) declaration.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters { 
        choice(name: 'NODE_VERSION', choices: ['NodeJS 9.6.1', 'NodeJS 7.7.0'], description: '') 
    }

    tools {
        nodejs params.NODE_VERSION
    }

    stages{
       stage("Run"){
            steps{
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: this would still restrict the team from using any version, since they can only use the versions added under Jenkins Global tools config. I am trying to give the app teams a way to chose any version.

Comment: You can use nodejs docker image as node and use string parameter to allow teams to chose any available docker image version

Comment: I added the choice param and published the available version of node installations for the team to use.